# Why does this integral inequality hold?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, inequality

The original question was:

> Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[a,b]$ and suppose that for every $a_1$ and $b_1$ in this interval:
>   $$\int_{a_1}^{b_1}f(x)\text{d}x=0$$
>
> Show that $f(x)=0$.

So the answer given proves that there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $\displaystyle f(x)>\frac{f(c)}{2}$, with $c\in (a,b)$.

Then the proof says that by picking $\delta$ small enough we can have $(c,c+\delta)$ or $(c-\delta,c)$ lies within the interval, which I understand.

Thus we can have: $$\int_c^{c+\delta}f(x)dx>\frac{f(c)}{2}\delta>0$$

Can someone please explain the last inequality for me please? I know from MVT that there exists a $c\in (a,b)$ such that $\displaystyle f(c)(b-a)=\int_a^b f(x)dx$, but not sure how I can go about using this to prove the above inequality.

Comment: Do you mean $\int_{a_1}^{b_1} f(x) \ dx = 0$ ?

Comment: Are you happy if someone proves that theorem to you in another way? You described the theorem very poorly?

Comment: what theorem are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\varepsilon>0$. Choose $\delta>0$ such that $|x-y|\leqslant\delta\implies |f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$. Since $[a,b]$ is compact, there exist $a=x_1<x_2<\cdots<x_n=b\in [a,b]$ such that $$[a,b]\subset\bigcup_{j=1}^n \left(x_j-\frac\delta2,x_j+\frac\delta2\right).$$

Suppose there exists $x^\star\in[a,b]$ such that $|f(x^\star)|>0$. Then $$x^\star\in\left[x_{j^\star}-\frac\delta2,x_{j^\star}+\frac\delta2\right]$$ for some $1\leqslant j^\star\leqslant n$. If $y\in\left[x_{j^\star}-\frac\delta2,x_{j^\star}+\frac\delta2\right]$ then $$0<|f(x^\star)|\leqslant |f(x^\star)-f(y)|+|f(y)|<\varepsilon+|f(y)|, $$ so $0<|f(x^\star)|\leqslant |f(y)|$. Assume $WLOG$ that $f(x^\star)>0$, then $0<f(x^\star)\leqslant |f(y)|$ and continuity of $f$ implies that $f(y)>0$. But this means that $f$ is strictly positive on $\left[x_{j^\star}-\frac\delta2,x_{j^\star}+\frac\delta2\right]$, and so 
$$\int_{x_{j^\star}-\frac\delta2}^{x_{j^\star}+\frac\delta2} f(x)\ \mathsf dx \geqslant \delta f(x^\star)>0, $$ a contradiction.

Comment: Could you explain the last inequality for me? The one with the integral greater than or equal to delta. f(x). That was what confused me in the first place. Thanks!

Comment: The length of the interval on which $f$ is integrated is $$\left(x_{j^\star}+\frac\delta2\right)-\left(x_{j^\star}-\frac\delta2\right)= \delta. $$